# back up restore a site from a site collection

Tags: powershell, site-collection, backup, restore

so I have created a new site collection and web application. I have a site in a site collection that I want to back up and restore on. Was just wondering if it was possible and if it was how, to do a back up on the site in the site collection and restore it onto my new site collection

Comment: You need to use Export/Import, check this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee428301.aspx

Comment: will that import everything currently in the site like lists and workflows?

Comment: You should only use this method for sites which use OOTB lists without workflows and version history. It doesn't do to well with either of them.